# Remove from map in adapter

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewpager, adapter

Write next method for stop redrawing my view multiple times in `instantiateItem`.

```
override fun instantiateItem(container: ViewGroup, position: Int): Any {
    val view = map.getOrPut(position) {
        AuthorizationHeaderView(context = context)
    }
    updateViewContent(view, data[position])
    timeUpdateListeners.add(view as TimeUpdateListener)
    container.addView(view, 0)
    return view
}
```

Now want to add next code `map.remove(position)` in my `destroyItem()`.
But he also called multiple times.

How i can make remove from map and don t redraw my view?

Comment: "But he also called multiple times" - how many times? Are you aware that ViewPager caches a certain number of Fragments to make swiping possible?

Comment: `destroyItem` called 3 times

Comment: @Anatolii  It will be more difficult, maybe there is a way not to create a map variable and use the container itself?

Comment: @Anatolii to prevent instantiating items android instantiateItem. I have due to the fact that the view is redrawn, the picture starts to flicker

Comment: @Anatolii ViewPager, second question don t understand